Trouble Reproducing Kuramoto Model Simulation from Paper Using PyTorch and 4th Order Runge-Kutta in Python
I am using the 4th order Runge-Kutta method to simulate the Kuramoto model.
I need to use the GPU, so I am using pytorch for calculations.
I am trying to reproduce a paper's result (DOI: 10.1103/PhysRevE.65.026139, FIG. 1.) to verify that my code is working properly, but my code gives wrong results. It is not completely off, but not good enough to argue that my code is working. I have given the same conditions except that the paper uses Heun's Method.
enter image description here
Here is my code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch

# Initial settings
sample_size = 100

t_max = 4 * 1e3
t_transient = 2 * 1e3 # transient datas are discarded
dt = 0.05
step_max = int(t_max / dt)
step_transient = int(t_transient / dt)

pi = torch.tensor(torch.pi, dtype=torch.float64, device='cuda')
i = torch.tensor(1j, dtype=torch.complex128, device='cuda')

N = 800

k_space = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0, 51)
r_plot = np.zeros_like(k_space)


# Kuramoto Model
def f(theta, w, K, A):

    phi = -theta + theta.reshape(-1, 1)
    return w + K * torch.sum(A * torch.sin(phi), axis = 0) / N


# Runge-Kutta 4th order
def RK4(f, theta, w, K, A):

    F1 = dt * f(theta, w, K, A)
    F2 = dt * f(theta + F1/2, w, K, A)
    F3 = dt * f(theta + F2/2, w, K, A)
    F4 = dt * f(theta + F3, w, K, A)

    return theta + (F1 + 2*F2 + 2*F3 + F4) / 6



r_t = torch.zeros(step_max - step_transient , dtype=torch.float64, device='cuda')
r_s = torch.zeros(sample_size, dtype=torch.float64, device='cuda')


for m, K in enumerate(k_space):
    for sample_num in range(sample_size):

        step = 0

        theta = torch.randn(N, dtype=torch.float64, device='cuda')
        theta = torch.remainder(theta, 2 * pi)
        # Mean field connection
        A = (torch.ones([N, N], dtype=torch.float64) - torch.eye(N, dtype=torch.float64)).to(device = 'cuda')
        # Natural frequencies from Gaussian
        w = torch.randn(N, dtype=torch.float64, device='cuda')


        while step < step_transient:

            theta = RK4(f, theta, w, K, A)
            theta = torch.remainder(theta, 2 * pi)
            step += 1

        while step < step_max:

            order_parameter = torch.sum(torch.exp(i * theta)) / N
            r_t[step - step_transient] = order_parameter.abs()

            theta = RK4(f, theta, w, K, A)
            theta = torch.remainder(theta, 2 * pi)
            step += 1

        r_s[sample_num] = r_t.mean()
        r_plot[m] = r_s.mean()


# drawing graphs and etc
plt.plot(k_space, r_plot, 'bo')
plt.show()

print(k_space)
print(r_plot)

I have tried:
-Changing the order of indexes of the tensors.
-Using the 2nd order RK (Heun's Method).
-Tried using both row and column vectors each.
This have been challenging me for weeks. Please give me some help :)

Your function f() seems to be returning something slightly different from Eqn 1 in that paper. You are dividing by N; the paper would imply dividing by -2k, with k (little k!) =3. Also, surely theta should be uniformly-distributed, not normally distributed. Please add to your post: (a) how to run your code; (b) your results.

I am re-calculating the process now, but the distribution of theta seems to be it! (At least that is what I think)

@lastchance Yes, the initial condition was indeed the problem. Thank you for the insight!!
